# REST API and CURL

Tags: android, rest, api, curl, retrofit

I am new to REST development and am writing a REST client to communicate with the Bitbucket API using Retrofit2.0

I thought communicating with the server API means sending a request in the following form

```
@GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
    Call<List<Contributor>> contributors(
            @Path("owner") String owner,
            @Path("repo") String repo
    );
```

I thought the API documentation should provide the necessary information about endpoints and parameters and so on.

But when I take a look at Bitbucket's API, all I got was the instruction on how to use cURL to do something, like [this instruction -](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D#post) for creating a new repository.

As far as I'm concerned, cURL is a Linux library and helps to facilitate a request to the API right from a Linux terminal.

My questions are:

- How are cURL and REST connected to each other?
- How do I use and implement cURL in my Rest client application?
- With the documentation provided by Bitbucket, which is the right way to implement a request to make the server create a new repository?

Comment: You can use cURL to perform REST calls. You do not need to implement cURL into your client. You need to translate a cURL request into the client framework.

Comment: thank you. Can you be more specific about the implementation of cURL into client or translating a cURL request into client framework? Does that mean I am going to actually use cURL in my code? How do I do that with Retrofit2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cURL is not REST. One is a tool, the other is a style of software architecture. You can use cURL to perform REST calls from the command line, but you do not need to implement it in your client application since there are likely tools available. Retrofit (actually just OkHttp) is one example.

Firstly, see `curl -X POST`? That means you need a POST request, not a `@GET` as you have in the code.

Secondly, that link you provided doesn't list `contributors` as an endpoint to the API.

Moving on, you need some JSON object that can represent this object to POST.

```
{
    "scm": "git",
    "project": {
        "key": "{ba516952-992a-4c2d-acbd-17d502922f96}"
    }
}
```

You can use libraries such as Jackson, Gson, Moshi, etc. to create a Java class Object that represents this data. Something like.

```
class Repo {
    String scm;
    Project project;
}

class Project {
    String key;
}
```

Then, I recommend remove the leading `/` from the annotation URL, as that needs to be appended to the base url.

```
@POST("repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
Call<List<Contributor>> contributors(
        @Path("owner") String owner,
        @Path("repo") String repo,
        @Body Repo data
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't have differentiated between cURL and REST. Can you give me a tutorial or a show-me-how link on how I could use Gson to create a Java Object to represent the data like you said?

Comment: Links and tutorials are off-topic for StackOverflow. Your keywords have already been said. Java objects and Gson. I trust your ability to find that information on your own